# HAProxy throws a CSFR error even after passing the headers for client

Tags: rest, server, load-balancing, amazon-elb, haproxy

There is a Java backend hosted on Tomcat, the two different application(sessions) for the java backend are running a common database to replicate the session for the server and the load balancer is configured using HAProxy.

But there is this error:  potential cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attack thwarted, method:POST, uri:/jw/web/console/app/test2/1/form/create, error:Request Token does not match the Master Token)

I have tried the following HAProxy cfg but still facing the same issue.

```
global
    log /dev/log local0
    log /dev/log local1 notice
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon

defaults
    log global
    mode http
    option httplog
    option dontlognull
    timeout connect 5000ms
    timeout client 50000ms
    timeout server 50000ms

frontend http_front
    bind *:80
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-For %[src]
    http-request set-header X-Forwareded-Proto https if {ssl_fc }
    default_backend http_back

backend http_back
    balance roundrobin
    server webserver1 192.168.0.101:80 check
    server webserver2 192.168.0.102:80 check
```